# css how do i fix a single nested div when scrolling the other layered/nested contents in a container?

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-position

I have seen a number of interesting posts on the subject of fixed position elements, but I have a problem that I can't solve.

I have a number of nested divs inside a scrolling div container as in my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/drHam/1/)

```
<div id="bottom" class="bottombox">
<div id="first" class="firstbox">
<div id="second" class="secondbox">
<div id="third" class="thirdbox">
<div id="top" class="topbox">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


.bottombox
{
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:0px;
Position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height:200px;
overflow:auto;
background-color: darkblue;
}

.firstbox
{
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:10px;
width: 700px;
height:50px;
background-color: lightblue;
}

.secondbox
{
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:10px;
Position: absolute;
width: 700px;
height:50px;
background-color: brown;

}


.thirdbox
{
margin-top:30px;
margin-left:10px;
width: 100px;
height:100px;
/*Position: fixed;*/    
background-color: white;
}


.topbox
{
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:10px;
width: 700px;
height:500px;
background-color: darkgray;
}
```

As you can see there are a number of "layers" which scroll together. The problem I have is that I want just the white box to stay fixed in relation to the bottom box which is in effect the container.

Can this be done with CSS? If not, what about Jquery to dynamically update its position?

Comment: For starters, you're missing a closing DIV. Also, the "Position" property needs to be lowercase.

Comment: Is it necessary for the div's to be nested? I was wondering if what you are trying to achieve could be achieved in some other way.

Comment: @diodeus thanks for pointing that out, apologies I just whacked it together before leaving work!

Comment: @sassyboy yes layers are absolutely necessary - they contain images and it's the interplay that requires a layer mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any way to do this in CSS, but here's a jquery solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/drHam/7/

```
$("#bottom").scroll(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".thirdbox").css("top",$this.scrollTop())
                  .css("left",$this.scrollLeft());            

    $(".topbox").css("top", $this.scrollTop()*-1)
                .css("left",$this.scrollLeft()*-1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible with pure CSS.

I worked out a solution with jquery, see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drHam/6/):

```
var bottom = $("#bottom");
var third = $("#third");
var top = $("#top");

bottom.scroll(function() {
    third.css("left", bottom.scrollLeft());
    third.css("top", bottom.scrollTop());
    top.css("left", -bottom.scrollLeft());
    top.css("top", -bottom.scrollTop());
});
```

Comment: your solution also works, but the other person got there first. plus one for equality